# I cannot get my card game program to work

Tags: c#

I have been trying to create a simple card game to practise my C# but got stuck while trying to create a deck of cards. I realise that the way I am doing it is not at all good or how you're supposed to do it but now I just want to see how I would be able to get it to work as a learning expirience more than anything. I am storing a bunch of Card objects from my Card class in a dictionary called Deck.

```
internal class Deck
{
    public Dictionary<string, Card> deck = new Dictionary<string, Card>();

    public Deck()
    {
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                deck.Add(String.Format("card{0}", k.ToString()), new Card((i+1), (j+1)));
            }
        }
    }

    public void Deck_Display()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        {

            Card aaa = deck[String.Format("card{0}", i.ToString())];
            Console.WriteLine($"{aaa.GetSuit()}, {aaa.GetRank()}");
            Console.WriteLine("\n");

        }
    }
```

while trying to display any individual card or the entire deck in Deck_Display it simply displays the last card in the deck every time. When I literally copy paste the Deck_display code into the loop where Deck is created it does exactly what I want, which also makes no sense.
Please tell me what I am doing wrong, it is probably something very stupid...

also here is my main method and card class in case somehow that has something to do with it:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Deck bruh = new Deck();
        bruh.Deck_Display();
    }
}


internal class Card
{
    public static int suit;
    public static int rank;

    public Card(int suit1, int rank1)
    {
        suit = suit1;
        rank = rank1;
    }

    public int GetSuit()
    {
        return suit;
    }

    public int GetRank()
    {
        return rank;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not changing the value of `k` in your init function, therefore you are always storing your cards in `deck["card0"]`. In your display function, you are accessing `deck["card0"]` through `deck["card51"]`

Comment: By the way, inside your `Card` class, you declared `suit` and `rank` as `static` which means they do not depend on an instance. This means that if you create `var a = new Card(1, 2)` and `var b = new Card(3, 4)`, both `a.GetSuit()` and `b.GetSuit()` will equal `3`, and both `a.GetRank()` and `b.GetRank()` willl equal `4`.

Answer (score 1):

As you state that you are just learning, then I would suggest some more fundamental changes which should help make the code easier to understand and easier for you to build on as well.  And help you also identify problems in if you have any later on.

If you don't know some of these concepts, then it is also a learning experience for you, and you can google to learn more about them.  They are fundamental, so will bode well for your future programming life.

Firstly don't use a number to represent the suite of the card, but rather an enum

```
public enum CardSuite { Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades }
```

Next, you can change your Card class to use properties, and not internal fields.  This will also save you some coding.  So now your class looks like this

```
 //Your new enum
 public enum CardSuite { Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades}

 internal class Card
 {
     //This are now properties with a getter & setter so you don't need to implement those as separate methods.  
     //Also, note the uppercase first letter.

     public CardSuite Suite { get; set; }
     public int Rank { get; set; }

     //Constructor also now uses the enum
     public Card(CardSuite suite, int rank)
     {
         Suite = suite;
         Rank = rank;
     }
 }
```

I also believe that you don't really need a dictionary to store your cards.  So if you change this to a list, then you can make things simpler.

So then you can change your Deck class to look like this

```
internal class Deck
{
     //This is now a list and a property.  Although you could make this an internal field
     public List<Card> CardDeck { get; set; } = new List<Card>();

     public Deck()
     {
         //You can start your loop at value 1 instead of 0
         //Then just change your exit condition from < to <=
         for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++)
         {
             //Now we need to loop each of the Suites in our enum.
             //This is a little trickier, but perfectly possible
             foreach(CardSuite suite in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardSuite)))
             {
                 //Adding to our deck is now much simpler code.
                 CardDeck.Add(new Card(suite, i));
             }
         }
     }
...
```

Note that as you now use an Enum for the Suite, then you need to loop this in a `foreach` to get each of the Suites

And the Deck_Display can also be changed to reflect the other changes you have made

```
     public void Deck_Display()
     {
         //this is just a counter for display purposes
         int cardNum = 1;

         //We can also use a foreach, this is better than a for loop with a fixed number.  As the number of cards might not always be the same!
         foreach(var card in CardDeck)
         { 
             Console.WriteLine($"Card{cardNum++} is {card.Suite}, {card.Rank}");
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your code by using k++ instead of k.

`deck.Add(String.Format("card{0}", (k++).ToString()), new Card((i+1), (j+1)));`

I would however suggest changing your dictionary to use int as the key instead of string.
`Dictionary<int, Card> deck`
This will remove the need for all the string manipulation and also make it easier to read.

You can then change your add line to the following:
`deck.Add(k++, new Card((i+1), (j+1)));`

You will then also need to this line:
`Card aaa = deck[String.Format("card{0}", i.ToString())];`
to:
`Card aaa = deck[i];`

Refer to the full solution below

```
internal class Deck
{
    public Dictionary<int, Card> deck = new Dictionary<int, Card>();

    public Deck()
    {
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                var card = new Card((i+1), (j+1));
                deck.Add(k++, card);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Deck_Display()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        {

            Card aaa = deck[i];
            Console.WriteLine($"{aaa.GetSuit()}, {aaa.GetRank()}");
            Console.WriteLine("\n");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, yes I did in fact miss the k++, however even after adding it, with or without implementing your int key solution, the output of the program is still wrong - it just outputs (13, 4) 52 times.